# Eclipse's cheat sheet repository/directory

Tags: eclipse

If it exists, where can I find an Eclipse Cheat Sheet Repository?

I mean, Eclipse has this "Cheat Sheet" feature (Help -> Cheat Sheets), but although being an easy and powerful feature I haven't seen people using it, for example for Tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closer you can get is what [VonC answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515208/eclipses-cheat-sheet-repository-directory/515261#515261) answered. After researching over the internet I couldn't find a central place where you can download cheat-sheets and use it as tutorials.

Maybe a market niche for those tech-entrepreneurs. :D

Comment: -1 for selecting your own answer as correct, though you refer to another answer as being the correct one.

Comment: well, if you read thoroughly you will notice that my question is where to find a REPOSITORY of cheat sheets.

and the short and simple answer is: there's no such place/website.

whatever... :-)

Comment: +1 You are right, there is not such a place, so I agree that's the correct answer... the +1 was just for Karmic balance =P

Answer (score 3):

As [mark mentionned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/515208#515227), if you have installed plugins, chances are they come with their cheat sheet.

As mentionned in this IBM article [Building cheat sheets in Eclipse V3.2](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecl-cheatsheets/), you can:

- make a Help search for the term "plug-in": it will return cheat sheets -- along with other content -- that match your query.
  But refining your search by adding "cheat sheet" to the query might narrow the results too much and exclude useful content.
- **explicitly show the cheat sheet results if you display the search results in categories**, using the category button.

[image: Cheet Sheets]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to the [Dzone's one](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-eclipse?oid=hom7187).

Good Luck!

Comment: I don't mean a Cheat Sheet for eclipse.
I mean a collection of Cheat Sheets to be used inside Eclipse.